# Javascript load Array from Text File

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

so to quickly explain if i change `myObj from = array` to `myObj = { the content of the callback.txt file }`
then this works. But when i try to call the contents into the var it doesn't when i call array into the innerHTML i see the full contents on the page. So I know the file is loading correctly, however I am unable to get it to parse the file for the information I want or to run it as an array.

the array file as

```
{ "information": [
  { 
    "Telephone # Dialed": "8555551234",
    "Employee ID": "XYZ456",
    "IncidentID": "INC000022222226",
    "Domain": "CORP",
    "Tier": "903",
    "HierarchyCode": "HACA4564S",
    "First Name": "Jane",
    "Last Name": "Smith",
    "City": "NORTH LAS VEGAS",
    "State": "NV",
    "Office Phone": "1234",
    "CallbackNumber": "4567",
    "Callback Successful": "N/A",
    "Callback Attempts": "0"
  },
  {
    "Telephone # Dialed": "8555551234",
   "Employee ID": "XYZ456",
    "IncidentID": "INC000022222228",
    "Domain": "CORP",
   "Tier": "903",
   "HierarchyCode": "HACA4564S",
   "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Smith",
    "City": "NORTH LAS VEGAS",
    "State": "NV",
    "Office Phone": "555",
    "CallbackNumber": "1234",
    "Callback Successful": "N/A",
    "Callback Attempts": "0"
  }
]
}
```

and the JavaScript as

```js
var array = [];
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
    array = text.split(/\n|\r/g);
    var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    array = obj.information;
    var listener = document.getElementById("submitThis");


    listener.onclick = function() {

      var incident = document.getElementById("incident").value;
      var myObj, i, j, x = "";
      myObj = array;
      for (i in myObj.information) {
        if (myObj.information[i].IncidentID == incident) {
          for (j in myObj.information[i].CallbackNumber) {
            x = myObj.information[i].CallbackNumber;
          }
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;

    }
  }
}


xmlhttp.open("GET", "callback.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p id="test"></p>
  <input type="text" id="incident">
  <input type="button" id="submitThis" value="make it happen">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to access a object inside the array that isn't there (you already called that earlier in your code).

```
<html>
<body>


<p id="test"></p>
<input type="text" id="incident"> 
<input type="button" id="submitThis"  value="make it happen">
<script>
var array = [];
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
//array = text.split(/\n|\r/g);
var obj = JSON.parse(text); 
array = obj.information;
var listener = document.getElementById("submitThis");


listener.onclick = function() { 

var incident = document.getElementById("incident").value;
var myObj, i, j, x = "";
myObj = array ;
for (i in myObj) {
if ( myObj[i].IncidentID == incident ) {
  for (j in myObj[i].CallbackNumber) {
   x = myObj[i].CallbackNumber ;
  }
  }
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;

}
  }
}


xmlhttp.open("GET", "callback.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

At `array = obj.information;` you already access *information*. Then you try to get it again in your for loop and the code inside the for loop (ie: `for (i in myObj.information) {`).

Also I commented out `array = text.split(/\n|\r/g);` because it wasn't doing anything in your code. And you don't want to split the JSON input before running `JSON.parse` anyway.

I hope this helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.